# Update a pandas data frame column using Apply,Lambda and Group by Functions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame in the format mentioned in the screenshot below. Column '**Candidate Won**' has only '**loss**' as the column value for all the rows. I want to update the Column 'Candidate Won' to a value 'won' if the corresponding row's '**% of Votes**' is **maximum** when grouped by '**Constituency**' Column otherwise the value should be 'loss'. I want to achieve the result by using a combination of apply, lambda, and group by, instead of using loops/iterations.

DataFrame : (df_andhrapradesh)

[image]

Code below works for a specific constituency in the data frame :

```
df_amalapuram=df_andhrapradesh[df_andhrapradesh['Constituency']=='Amalapuram']
df_amalapuram['Candidate Won']=df_amalapuram['% of Votes'].apply(lambda x:"Won" if x==df_amalapuram['% of Votes'].max() else "Loss")
```

Tried something like below to make it work for the entire data frame which has different constituencies but it failed:

```
df_andhrapradesh['Candidate Won']=df_andhrapradesh['% of Votes'].apply(lambda x:"Won" if x==df_andhrapradesh.groupby('Constituency')['% of Votes'].max() else "Loss")
```

Comment: You want to change the column "Candidate Won" value to won if the '% of votes' column is maximum in each group where grouping based on 'Constituency' column, right?

Answer (score 0):

I used '**Apply**' function to every row in the pandas data frame and created a **custom function** to return the value for the '**Candidate Won**' Column using data frame,**row-level 'Constituency','% of Votes'**

**Custom Function Code**:

```
def update_candidateresult(df,a,b):
max_voteshare=df.groupby(df['Constituency']==a)['% of Votes'].max()[True]
if b==max_voteshare:
    return "won"
else:
    return "loss"
```

Final Code :

```
 df_andhrapradesh['Candidate Won']=df_andhrapradesh.apply(lambda row:update_candidateresult(df_andhrapradesh,row['Constituency'],row['% of Votes']),axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to read the maximum value index of each group and change the value of the candidate:

```
df.loc[df.groupby('Constiteuncy').idxmax().values.ravel(), 'candidate'] = 'won'
```

But if you prefer to use apply and lambda as you mentioned, you could try this:

```
index_max = df.groupby(['Constiteuncy'])['Vote'].apply(lambda x: x.idxmax())
df.loc[index_max , 'candidate'] = 'won'
```